# How to concatenate the two consecutive values obtained in a Array adapter?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Given below is the code snippet for receiving and displaying data in BluetoothChat Code. I want to combine(concatenate) two consecutive values and display it as one value. Is this possible?

BluetoothChat.java

```
// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {

          case MESSAGE_READ:

           byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;       

           String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

           mConversationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);

           break;
           }
             }
              }
```

Comment: are you ganna do this all time for every 2 messages ?

Comment: yes..for every two messages...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :** it will add new item to the end of your previous list.

```
 mConversationArrayAdapter.addAll(readMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's for every 2 messages, here is a workaround :

```
// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    int c = 0;
    String s ="";
        switch (msg.what) {


       case MESSAGE_READ:

          byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;       

           String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
           c++;
           s += readMessage;
           if(c==2) {
           mConversationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);
           c=0;
           s=""
           }

           break;
       }}}
```